# storing the value of a tuple in a variable that is randomized

Tags: python, tuples

```
colours = [('green', 1.4), ('blue', 4.067), ('yellow', 6.56), ('black', 9.056), ('red', 10.23)]
```

I have randomized one of these values thorough the following code and got the index of that value in the list:

```
colour_name = random.choice(colours)[0]
colour_number = [i for i, t in enumerate(colours) if t[0] == colour_name][0] + 1
```

Lets say I have randomized the colour green with the index 0. How do I also get the value 1.4 that belongs to green?

To be clear, I want the value 1.4 to be stored in a separate variable, just like "green" is stored in the variable "colour_name".

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you corrently, you want to return "color name" and "color number" from a given index. Tuples can be accessed by index, just like lists. Therefore It would be: `colours[0][0]` --> "green" and `colours[0][1]` --> "1.4".

Answer (score 2):

`random.choice` is already returning both the name and the value; you are just discarding the value. You don't need to know the index of the choice; you just need to unpack the returned tuple.

```
colour_name, colour_value = random.choice(colours)
```